# Using LOOP to find key with maximum value in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

So I'm trying to find the key in a dictionary with the highest value, ONLY using a loop (while or for, doesn't matter). I'm already aware of the function max() where I could find the key with the highest value that way (max(d, key=d.get)), but I'm trying to do it with a loop. However, I've only been able to build a loop to find a maximum value, not the key that corresponds to it. I have already checked several articles, but I have not come upon an answer. If someone could help me find one, or explain how I can modify my code to find the KEY, not the max value, that'd be fantastic.

Here is my code:

```
maximum = 0
for k in letterCounts:
    if letterCounts[k] > maximum:
        maximum = letterCounts[k]
print(maximum)
```

I'm aware that a loop isn't the easiest way to get what I want, but it is a requirement for an assignment I'm trying to complete.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: just create a `max_key` name which you will assign `k` to `if letterCounts[k] > maximum`.

Comment: Oh my god, that's such an easy fix, I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maximum = 0
max_key = None
for k in letterCounts:
    if letterCounts[k] > maximum:
        maximum = letterCounts[k]
        max_key = k

print(max_key)
print(maximum)
```